# preferredStatusBarStyle and presentModalView Controllers

Tags: ios

```
@implementation UIViewController (preferredStatusBar)
-(UIStatusBarStyle) preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
@end
```

I made this category so all the controllers implements this attribute, `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` can change during application.

Everything works fine except for modal controllers. They ignore completely status bar style.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that you are loading a modal view controller as a `UINavigationController`. But you haven't provided enough information to be sure.

If this is the case you would need to override the method `preferredStatusBarStyle` for the `UINavigationController` as well.

Comment: UINavigationController is a subclass from UIViewController, it receives also this behaviour (tried with breakpoints )

Comment: Correct, but you have a category. Does the UINavigationController use this category? Have you seen that this method is being called in the appropriate navigation controller.

Comment: Right. I also refer to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999019/how-to-change-uistatusbarstyle-in-ios-7-in-modal-views-with-navigation-bar - When you say it is ignored, what is the style being used? Is this setup in storyboard, have you confirmed there is no override in there.

Comment: The question is 100% related with the posted one. And no anwswer to... at least discover it works on none navigation controllers