# Storyboard-set iOS 7 Status Bar not shown in right style

Tags: ios, ios7, uistoryboard, uistatusbar

I have two Scenes in a Storyboard; a dark one and a light one.
Set to `Default` in the Simulated metrics' Status Bar section, the light scene's bar is dark and works correctly. The dark scene's is set the same way to `Light Content` style but it doesn't change.
No mention of the bar anywhere in the code itself, what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simulated metrics is only for XCode. You need to set this for the view in the views viewcontroller.

[UIViewController:preferredStatusBarStyle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/preferredStatusBarStyle/%%22)

[StackoverFlow question covering the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999019/how-to-change-uistatusbarstyle-in-ios-7-in-modal-views-with-navigation-bar)