# ios7 status bar changing back to black on modal views?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, statusbar, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have my app setup and everything works great until I call my image picker and my mail controller. On each of those views the UIStatusBar changes to black even though I have

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

and View controller-based status bar appearance set to YES.

Any idea how to control the light color of these modal views? See the images - the first one is the entire app, working great. The second is the image picker after the image library is shown and the third is the mail composer.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Exact duplication found.

Comment: I've tried this method and it does not work for me.

Comment: Hey, that works for me

1) Set `View controller-based status bar` appearance to `NO`
2) Set `Status bar style` to `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` (just copy that value)
3) In appDelegate use `    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put this on the view controller presenting the modal controller

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle) preferredStatusBarStyle { 
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; 
}
```